# Quadratic Equations $\bmod p^k$

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory

As part of a larger program, I need to solve $A x^2+B x+C \equiv 0 \pmod {p^k}$ for prime $p$. Right now I'm doing this by calling

`Reduce[A*x^2+B*x+C==M*p^k,{x,M},Integers]`

and then parsing this to find what I need (i.e. usually just assigning `C[1]->0` and ignoring `M` results).

But when $A$, $B$, $C$, and especially $p^k$ start to get large (e.g. $A,B,C \approx 10^{30}$ and $p^k \approx 10^{70}$), there is quite a lag.

Is there a faster way to find solutions for $x \bmod p^k$?

Thanks!

Comment: Could try to rewrite it in a way that uses `PowerMod[...,1/2,p^k]`.

Comment: So there's nothing that implements Hensels Lemma a.k.a lifting? I guess I'll have to write my own...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `PowerMod` for prime power moduli will do lifting. Also `Roots` (and thus `Solve` and `Reduce`) will use Hensel lifting. The reason to prefer `PowerMod` is that if I recall correctly it has special case code for square roots. The general case uses degree 1 of the distinct degree factorization algorithm and I'm guessing that's the expensive step.

Answer (score 2):

When `a` is invertible and there are two solutions (the "nice" case), the code below will find one root. It seems to be around 3x faster than `Reduce[...,x, Modulus->p^k]. It does not check for various error conditions though.

```
solveQuadratic[a_, b_, c_, p_, k_] := Module[
  {x, ainv, cp, corr, pk = p^k, rhs},
  ainv = PowerMod[a, -1, pk];
  corr = Mod[ainv*b*PowerMod[2, -1, pk], pk];
  cp = Mod[-c + a*PowerMod[corr, 2, pk], pk];
  rhs = Mod[ainv*cp, pk];
  Mod[PowerMod[rhs, 1/2, pk] - corr, pk]
  ]
```

One can negate this mod p^k to get the other root.

When there are more than 2 roots this still seems to find one.

Comment: It appears that PowerMod[x,1/2,p] uses the Tonelli-Shanks modular square root algorithm (or a variant of this) for p prime.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Please see comments by belisarius below in relation to the large $p^k$.

My original answer (below):

You can add `Modulus` option to `Solve` or `Reduce`. Just a simple example:

```
Reduce[x^2 - 4 x + 9 == 0, x, Modulus -> 3^5]
```

yields:

```
x == 103 || x == 144
```

and

```
Solve[x^2 - 4 x + 9 == 0, x, Modulus -> 3^5]
```

yields:

```
{{x -> 103}, {x -> 144}}
```

Comment: For large numbers you get `Reduce::munsp: Reduce was unable to solve the system. Increasing the value of "MaxModularPoints" in SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"] may help. >>`

Comment: But `Reduce[Mod[a*x^2 + b*x + c, p^k] == 0, x, Integers]` works (although not very fast)

Comment: @belisarius thank you for the feedback. I just wished to express note this option. I completely missed the point of behaviour for large prime multiples. So, have learned a lot from your comments...

Comment: But I haven't tried to increase "MaxModularPoints". Perhaps you should, at least enough to cope with the figures mentioned by the OP